# Simple Regex Replace Visual Script

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code

```
<% 
txt = ""+(rs_email.Fields.Item("g_email_body").Value)+""
Set objReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objReg.Pattern = "[activate]"
activate = (objReg.Replace(txt,"http://www.gamtool.com/activate.asp?id="+(Recordset1.Fields.Item("g_userbase_id").Value)+""))
%>
```

When I run the code I get an error on the last line

```
activate = (objReg.Replace(txt,"http://www.gamtool.com/activate.asp?id="+(Recordset1.Fields.Item("g_userbase_id").Value)+""))
    %>
```

any ideas why I am getting the error?

I have updated the code above to the following:

```
<%
  Set regEx = New RegExp
  regEx.Global = true
  regEx.IgnoreCase = True
  regEx.Pattern = "\[activate\]"
  strText = ""+(rs_email.Fields.Item("g_email_body").Value)+""
  activate = regEx.Replace(strText, ""+(Recordset1.Fields.Item("g_userbase_id").Value)+"")
%>
```

If I change the  ""+(Recordset1.Fields.Item("g_userbase_id").Value)+"") to any value but insert the value static then it works.

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual text from the error?

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch /email.asp, line 49 - This is the line as above

Comment: Try splitting the problematic line into multiple lines:

1) `value = Recordset1.Fields.Item("g_userbase_id").Value`
2) `url = "http://www.gamtool.com/activate.asp?id=" + (value) + ""`
3) `activate = (objReg.Replace(txt, url))`


On which of these lines does the error occur?

Comment: Hi Helen the problem seem to be the dynamic value from the db

Comment: What is the type of the g_userbase_id field then? It looks like you're trying to convert it into a string by concatenating empty strings. First you should use an explicit conversion function like CStr() to make it the type you need, and/or you should be using an ampersand for concatenation instead of a plus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gerald Ferreira: Instead of using `+`, use `&` to concatenate. You're getting the type mismatch error because VB Script thinks you're trying to *add* which, of course, isn't the same as concatenating.